# devnagari script in terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

When I try to write in terminal in devnagari script, the vowels are shown separated from consonants (unlike how it is written).

The same is the case when I open a file containing devnagari characters in vim in terminal.

Is there a way to get these characters printed properly?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install mlterm ; mlterm`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## This problem is fixed in Ubuntu 19.04 and above

The gnome-terminal 3.32 supports Devanagari and other Indian fonts rendering.

## Old Answer

You may be out of luck. Even though Devnagari (Hindi, etc.) script works well in most text input areas like gedit, browsers, and word processors, it looks like complex indic scripts like Devnagari are not supported in the default gnome terminal. However, some people were working on [Devanagari support on GNOME Terminal](http://indiclanguagecomputing.wordpress.com/2011/01/06/devanagari-support-on-gnome-terminal/) and the results are available [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/vteindic/home/Indic%20Language%20Support%20for%20VTE/).

I have no idea how this tweaked version of gnome terminal will fit into Ubuntu. As usual use caution when installing programs, apps and codes from unknown sources.

Another option is to install `fbterm` from Ubuntu Software Center. See the comments section of [How can I get colors in TTY working correctly?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/57086/how-can-i-get-colors-in-tty-working-correctly) for how to make it work.

Hope this helps

Comment: OK. Are there any terminals in the distros that support rendering of complex scripts like devnagari?

Comment: I have added fbterm to the answer. Let me know if you can get it to work.

Comment: Nope. I am not able to start fbterm from Unity.

Comment: Try: add yourself to the `video` group. Then you should be able to start fbterm from terminal.

Comment: No. Does not work. Gives an error 'stdin isn't a interactive tty!'

Answer (score 4):

Please use `konsole`, it supports devanagari well. Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install konsole
```

Comment: Spot-on. This is the only thing that worked for me. It's kind of annoying that even sublime text doesn't support devnagari or any Indian scripts.

Answer (score 1):

VTE version 0.56 (gnome-terminal 3.32) fixed Devanagari rendering.