# Bangla Font issue in Terminal

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal, fonts, locale, unicode

I have a program that outputs Bangla in the terminal. But unfortunately, the output is not displayed properly by gnome-terminal in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The output should look like this:

> আপনাদের দোকান কবে খোলা থাকবে?

Instead it looks like this with a Ubuntu Mono font:

[image: Screenshot]

Further it looks like this with Kalpurush font that supports Bangla:

[image: Screenshot]

I have checked with xfd to see if the bangla character range is available in the two fonts. As expected, Ubuntu Mono had empty boxes in the character range, whereas Kalpurush had correct representational symbols.

Additionally, locale is set to UTF-8. `locale` output:

```
LANG=en_US.utf8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.utf8"
LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.utf8"
LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_GB.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

I have also tried with Bangla locale, but it did not work.
Moreover, Terminal character encoding is also set to Unicode(UTF-8). Yet, nothing worked.

So, then I tried out Guake Terminal Emulator. But it did not work either.

Now what can I do more to fix this issue?

Comment: `sudo apt install fonts-beng`

Comment: `fonts-beng` is already installed and the newest version.

Comment: Complex text rendering is not supported by VTE (the terminal emulation widget behind gnome-terminal and many more; let alone guake which uses an ancient version of VTE). See https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=584160. For the time being, you can try if one of the patches posted there gives you something good enough, or whether other (non VTE-based) emulators do it better.

Comment: Maybe use `konsole` instead of `gnome-terminal`: https://askubuntu.com/a/481786

Comment: Thanks for the info. It is really amazing that people have not solved this bug yet. @egmont

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your terminal font is set to Ubuntu Mono.

Install a font that does support the Bangla language, such as the Lohit Bengali font.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: You should at least read the comments first, if you are going to post an answer to a 5 year old question!